# Do Vulcans get a patina when exposed to the sun?

Tags: star-trek, biology, vulcan

Does exposure the sun add color to the skin of green blooded [Vulcans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_%28Star_Trek%29) in the same fashion that it tans red blooded humans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this information would show up anywhere as a conversation had in canon, so I am forced to speculate given what we have seen of Vulcans over the years.

- Vulcans come in a variety of melanin shades very much like humans. (See Tuvok.)

[image: T'pau, T'pol, and Tuvok]

*T'pau, T'pol, and Tuvok*

- It make sense they would have the ability if not the regular propensity for tanning under long-term exposure to UV light. In humans, tanning is a defense mechanism against exposure to solar exposure.
- Given the Vulcan sun is far brighter than the Earth's sun, (they have evolved a [secondary inner eyelid](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Inner_eyelid) or nictitating membrane to protect them from their sun's brightness) they may have evolutionary resistance to their sun making them far more resistant to their sun's radiation.

Comment: Now, square the long - meaning exposed to sun - ears with bright sun. Does not make much evolutionary sense :)

Comment: Hey, I didn't make them long. Perhaps their ears are simply better than ours at avoiding sunburn. Vulcans do seem to have quite a bit of physical engineering hinted at in their overall species design...

Comment: Don't Vulcans also have a higher resistance to injury and disease due to a denser cellular structure?